# shallow copy in compound list and simple list

Tags: python-3.x, shallow-copy

Why is the element in the original compound list changed when I try to change an element in the shallow copy, but not so for a simple list?

```
list7 = [[11],[12]] 

list8 = list7.copy()

list8[0][0] = 13


print('nlist7:', list7) 

print('nlist8:', list8)


nlist7: [[13], [12]] 

nlist8: [[13], [12]] 


XXXXXX

list1 = [11,12,13] 

list2= list11[:]

list2[0] = 14

print(list11)

[11, 12, 13]

print(list12)

[14, 12, 13]
```

Comment: Can you please tag your question with the programming language you're using?

Comment: python 3.6 using Jupyter notebook, Anaconda.